# x86 macOS terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, intel

I am trying to write a program that will find and print the primes under 255. The following program works fine in [visUAL](https://salmanarif.bitbucket.io/visual/):

```
    mov     r0, #1
    mov     r3, #0x100
L1
    mov     r1, r0
    mov     r2, #2      
    adds        r0,r0,#2        
    cmp     r0, #0x100 ; only testing 1-byte numbers
    bge     exit        
    bvs     exit        
L2
    mov     r1, r0
L3
    sub     r1,r1,r2        
    cmp     r1, #0
    bgt     L3      
    beq     L1      
    add     r2, r2, #1
    cmp     r2, r0
    bne     L2      
    add     r3,r3,#4        
    str     r0, [r3]
    b       L1
exit
```

I've attempted to port this to x86 for macOS, mostly using the x86 wikibook as reference. This is what I have so far:

```
;compile with
;   nasm -f macho FILE.asm
;   ld -o primes -e _main FILE.o
extern _printf
segment .data
segment .text
global _main
_syscall:
    int 0x80
    ret
_main:
    mov     eax, 1
    mov     ecx, 0x100
L1$:
    mov     edx, eax
    mov     ebx, 2
    add     eax,2
    cmp     eax, 0x100 ; only testing 1-byte numbers
    jge     exit
    jo      exit
L2$:
    mov     edx, eax
L3$:
    sub     edx,ebx
    cmp     edx, 0
    jg      L3$
    je      L1$
    add     ebx, 1
    cmp     ebx, eax
    jne     L2$
    add     ecx,4
    push dword  1
    push dword  eax
    push dword  1
    mov eax, 0x4
    call _syscall
    add esp, 12
    jmp     L1$
exit:
```

There are no errors/warnings when running nasm or ld, but `./primes` does not work. With fish (my normal shell), it prints nothing but `fish: './primes' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`. In bash or sh, it prints `Segmentation fault: 11`. As far as I can tell, this means I'm trying to access some memory that isn't allowed. However, I don't believe I'm accessing any memory at all. What is wrong? A clear way to make the code run correctly would be ideal, but just understanding the error would be very helpful.

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. remove extra spaces

Comment: @Prateek Okay, done. I didn't know that was the convention for assembly.

Comment: Well one obvious problem is that you don't use the sys_exit syscall to exit the program so that will likely cause a SIGSEGV. At label `exit:` you'd need  `mov eax, 0x1` `call _syscall`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you so much!!! There's no error now, but nothing is printing at all. Should I ask a different question or edit this? Or do you see the problem?

Comment: I'd suggest a new question.

Comment: It says I can only post once per 90 minutes. I'll ask tomorrow then.

Comment: Are you sure you're assembling this as 32-bit, not x86-64?  NVM, `push eax` wouldn't assemble in 64-bit mode, so that's not the problem.  I think OS X really does take args for `int 0x80` on the user-space stack with a gap for a return address, so that's probably right, if you have the right system-call numbers.  Use `strace` or whatever OS X equivalent there is to see what system calls you're actually making, and so you can see if they're returning errors.

Comment: @PeterCordes How would I tell? I'm using the two commands at the top of the file to assemble. I got the system call number from wikibooks.

Comment: `nasm -f macho FILE.asm` is definitely 32-bit.  `-f macho64` would be 64-bit.  On Linux, `ld` would need an option to specify 32-bit, but IDK about OS X.  When you run it under a debugger, if you only see EAX..ESP, then it's 32-bit mode.  But in the unlikely event you see RAX..R15, then `ld` took your 32-bit machine code and put it in a 64-bit executable (where the same `push` instruction would push 8 bytes).  Like I said, that's unlikely,

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much for the information! I'm going to try to disassemble some C programs to figure out my problem. Now I know why R8-15 wasn't working.